# Qt Maintenance Tool won't launch

Tags: qt

Launching the tool from the Start menu does nothing.

From the command line, I get the following error when running Qt's `MaintenanceTool.exe --verbose`:

```
"Cannot open file C:/Qt/MaintenanceTool.dat for reading: No such file or directory"
```

Anyone know how to fix it? I promise I didn't delete that file, though it is correct in saying it doesn't exist. I only have `MaintenanceTool.ini`. The installation log file doesn't mention any `.dat` files or give any errors at the end.

Edit: Seems to be a [bug in Qt](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-689). I'd still like to know how to work around it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, like you pointed out, and I just ran into it.  Thanks for the bug report link.  There's not a good workaround that I'm aware of within Qt; hopefully, they'll patch it soon.

However, on Windows, your machine will probably have a [shadow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) of `MaintenanceTool.dat`, created when you ran Windows Update.  To restore a shadow copy:

1. Right click on the `C:\Qt` folder (or wherever you installed Qt) and choose Properties.
2. Click the Previous Versions tab.
3. In reverse age order (newest first), open the various copies of the Qt folder, and see if they have `MaintenanceTool.dat`.

[image: Previous Versions window]

4. Once you find one, drag it into your real Qt folder alongside `MaintenanceTool.exe`, where it belongs.

The Maintenance Tool will complain about a "corrupt installation," but it seems to operate just fine.

Answer (score 7):

My solution was pretty simple. I renamed `MaintenanceTool.exe.new` and `MaintenanceTool.dat.new` to `MaintenanceTool.exe` and `MaintenanceTool.dat`. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

1 stage: rename your QT folder (c:/qt) to any name, for examaple "qt_dump"
2 stage: reinstall qt online installer without any packages, deselect all checks
3 stage: rename your new qt installed folder for example "qt_working", and folder from stage 1 rename to "qt", and replace files from "qt_working" to "qt".

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the Previous Versions tab as displayed above. I found making a backup of your .dat file before closing off the maintenance tool works as well, but it isn't pretty and is something that you need to be aware off before the problem hits you...

Answer (score 0):

Rename your old Qt folder as "Qt_dump"

Then install Qt again with "qt-unified-windows-x86-3.1.1-online" from the official website.

To avoid long installation, you may just install default setup.

After you finish the installation, now you can launch MaintenanceTool.exe from search window or controll panel.
Clear your temp folder. *might be clear the registry if need it.

Done. Good luck.